# Multi assert in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have set of many cases that I want to test on a single function.

Let's say:

```
@pytest.mark.unittest
def test_simple_test_id_odd():
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    for number in numbers:
        assert number % 2 == 0
```

When I run this it stops on the first number with the error. I want the test to go all over the numbers and check each one of them.

I don't want to write a test for each number, it does not make sense, it's too long.

How can I test all the numbers and raise error for every one of them that failed?

Comment: Write a *parameterised* test: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario I would prefer to use [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html):

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("number", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
def test_simple_test_id_odd(number):
    assert number % 2 != 0
```